# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object php

Tags: php

How to fix this code I don't know problem come from where ?

```
        $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, title, tags,thumb,views,duration,date,owner FROM `videos` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $position, $items_per_group");
        $results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
        $results->bind_result($id_r, $title_r, $tags_r,$thumb_r,$views_r,$duration_r,$date_r,$owner_r); //bind variables to prepared statement
        while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
        $resultsa = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,user FROM `users` where `owner`='$owner_r'");
        $resultsa->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
        $resultsa->bind_result($f,$user_getbyid); //bind variables to prepared statement
        $resultsa->fetch();
    ?>
    <a href="video/<?php echo $id_r; ?>">
    <div class="video">
    <div class="img"><img src="<?php echo $thumb_r; ?>"/></div>
    <div class="title"><h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($title_r); ?></h2></div>
    <div class="pub_by"><span id="pub_by_user">Published by : <a href="user/"><?php echo $user_getbyid; ?></a></span><span id="pub_time"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($date_r); ?></span></div>
    <div class="time"><?php echo $duration_r; ?></div>
    <div class="info">
    <ul>
    <li><?php echo $views_r; ?></li>
    <li>148</li>
    <li>45</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
    <?php
    }
        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

Please fix this code and explain me why it not work like that

Comment: Use Prepared Statements **with** binding parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible places where something went wrong - without knowing the line number it's impossible to say which.

One of your calls to `$mysqli->prepare` is failing, which suggests that the SQL you're generating is incorrect.

There are two variables in the first line of your example which aren't defined (according to the snippet posted at least), which will result in an incorrect query.

Comment: Error is declared in 
$resultsa->execute(); //Execute prepared Query